# Can Emacs be set to auto-stage (preferably with --intent-to-add) new files?

Tags: magit, git, vc

I often add a new file to a repo, make some other changes, then stage all, and commit all, forgetting that the new file is not yet tracked, so is not included in the stage all step. At least one editor (IntelliJ) has an option to auto-stage new files, which would be very helpful to me in Emacs. I guess this would be particularly helpful if it invoked --intent-to-add.

Is this feature present in magit or built-in in Emacs?

If not, I'd be interested in writing some elisp. Is there a hook run when magit sees a new untracked file, or would I have to add to the after-save-hook and query the git status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magit does not implement this and as far as I know VC/Emacs does not do so either.

Magit also does not provide a hook that is run "when it sees a new untracked" file but you could use `find-file-hook`, which is run when *you* see a untracked file. ;D

You probably want to use `magit-file-tracked-p` in your hook function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at writing some elisp. Is this something you'd be interested in add to magit, or do you see it as something outside of its scope?

Comment: I don't want to add this to Magit because this is not a workflow I am comfortable promoting.

Comment: Fair enough. Before I add this to my init.el (and maybe unwittingly degrade my workflow) would you mind explaining why it may not be desirable? I (and presumably some IntelliJ users) think it may be useful as an option at least.

Comment: For any future readers, this is the elisp I created: https://gist.github.com/tomdl89/d1c68aac21a66ec656b848503188a491